# using two versions of jquery in the same page returns 'Undefined is not a function'

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp

I tried using jQuery_1_9_1 and jQuery_1_4_2 in the same page
But when trying to open popups in my page I am getting 
Undefined type Err 'Undefined is not a function' at this point

```
jQuery_1_9_1.fn.track=function(){
    jQuery_1_9_1(this).each(function(){
        return new Track(jQuery_1_9_1(this));
```

Also I am using Mootools in my page .
Could anyone pls help why I am getting this error.

**Edit**

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='../assets/js/jquery-1.4.2.min.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript'> var jq = jQuery.noConflict(); </script>
```

I have given 1.4.2 in my template file and

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='../assets/js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js'>
<script type="text/javascript"> var jQuery_1_9_1 = jQuery.noConflict(true); </script>
```

in one of the commonly used JSP

Comment: Please show how you include the different versions, and how you set the `jQuery_1_9_1` variable.

Comment: <script type='text/javascript' src='../assets/js/jquery-1.4.2.min.js'></script> <script type='text/javascript'> var jq = jQuery.noConflict(); </script>   I have given 1.4.2 in my template file and  <script type='text/javascript' src='../assets/js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js'><script type="text/javascript">
     var jQuery_1_9_1 = jQuery.noConflict(true);
    </script> in one of the commonly used JSP

Comment: how do you try to open the popup? Could you add the code to your question as it is the cause for the error?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1566595/can-i-use-multiple-versions-of-jquery-on-the-same-page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1566595/can-i-use-multiple-versions-of-jquery-on-the-same-page)

Comment: try ``...$.noConflict...``

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you **DO NOT NEED** multiple versions of JQuery on a single page to achieve the desired functionality.

Secondly, since you are using Mootools and JQuery, best would be to use the following alternatives instead of the default `$` in JQuery:

1. Using the `jQuery` instance directly
2. Using `var jQ = jQuery.noConflict();`

Also, it would be best for applications like this to use Asynchronous Module Definition - something like [RequireJS](http://requirejs.org) to ensure you load only the JS files which are required for specific functionality.